# Importing MS Access data into VFP

Tags: ms-access-2010, visual-foxpro

I need to import data from an Access app into VFP tables. I have found solutions on the net for reading VFP data into Access but not the opposite. The connection string suggested by MS* seems to be missing something because I keep getting a dialog box asking me for the type of the source data

- "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=MyAccessApp.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

I would be grateful for any suggestion and/or explanation.

/bernard

Comment: Is this a one-off or something you need to repeat? If it's a one-off you may find it easier to export required tables from Access in DBF format.

Comment: Does the bitness (32 vs. 64 bit) of your installed ACE provider match the bitness of the process which uses it?

Comment: Does your connection string include the `Provider` keyword, as in `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are writing the program within VFP, then you can do a connect from VFP to the Access Database without the use of a "DSN", but requires a full connection string setting.  Once that is done, you can query the data down into a local VFP cursor, then do what you want once it is in VFP... copy to a VFP table, query subsets of data, add records to another VFP table by whatever criteria you need to process.

```
nAccessHandle = sqlstringconnect( "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb); DBQ=C:\YourFullPath\YourAccessDatabase.accdb;" )

if nAccessHandle < 1
   messagebox( "Invalid connection to access database" )
   return
endif 

*/ Valid handle, now, query down the data to a local VFP cursor
nSQLAns = SQLExec( nAccessHandle, "select * from YourAccessTable", "C_CursorInVFP" )

if nSQLAns < 1
   messagebox( "Unable to get any data..." )
   sqldisconnect( nAccessHandle )
   return
endif

*/ Done with connection
sqldisconnect( nAccessHandle )

select C_CursorInVFP
copy to C:\SomeOtherPath\NowItsAVFPTable

*/ Or, query from it within VFP or loop from it...
select C_CursorInVFP
scan
   */ Look for records in VFP to do/ignore as needed...
   select * from SomeVFPTable ;
      where SomeKey = C_CursorInVFP.KeyFromAccessTable;
      into cursor C_WasItFound readwrite

   if reccount( "C_WasItFound" ) > 0
      */ Do what if it WAS found
   else
      */ Do what if it WAS NOT found
   endif 
endscan
```

Comment: So is it a case of VFP being able to access other data sources with ODBC but not with OLEDB? (Forgive my ignorance but I haven't worked with VFP for many years, although once upon a time it was essentially my full-time job.)

Comment: Thank you all. DRApp, your answer works perfectly and it's much simpler than anything else I found ;-) All I need now is figure out why some of the Access text fields are turned into memo fields in VFP...
Alan, yes it needs to be repeated.
Gord, the word Provider was there, I just did not copy it. And I too, am back working with VFP after many years.
/bernard

Comment: @Gord No, VFP is perfectly able to use OLEDB,

Comment: @Bernard, glad it worked... also, click on help / tour for site etiquette too so users know when an questions has been resolved or others in similar know what worked instead of asking same / similar questions over and over.

Comment: is this line correct: `nSQLAns = SQLExec( nAccessHandle, "select * from YourAccessTable", "C_CursorInVFP" )`? Shouldn't it become `nSQLAns = SQLExec( nAccessHandle, "select * from YourAccessDatabase", "C_CursorInVFP" )`? What if we want to have *multiple* tables we need to access, and then between those tables there is a common column that allows us to join in data to perform manipulations?

Comment: This is great.  How can I query the Access metadata - to get a list of table names?